# Finding specific values in a string of numbers

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble trying to validate an interest rate. The conditions are as follows:
( Must be present. Must be numeric. Allowable values: 3.000 thru 16.000 inclusive.).

I am having trouble trying to determine if after the 1st digit is a number, if the next is also one. ie  "2N34" should come up as an error. Everytime i tried to use a for loop it just doesn't work. I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to test this and submit the proper error.

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:

```
function valIntRate(errMessages){

var rate = document.getElementById("intRate").value;
if (rate.length === 0){
    errMessages += "Interest rate can't be left empty";
}


if (rate < 3 || rate > 16){
        errMessages += "Rate must be between 3 and 16 inclusive";
}

return errMessages;
}
```

HTML (where the input field is) :

```
  <label class="label"> Interest  Rate </label>

      <input type="text" name="intRate" id="intRate" size="7" maxlength="6" >
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner That doesn't make sense in this context. Using && will ask if rate < 3 _and_ rate > 16 - but only one of those conditions can be true at any time, so it will always return False.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I saw later that also those greater than etc. are wrong as well

Comment: is dot a decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use isNaN(input);  to validate the numeric value. This should work.

```
function valIntRate(errMessages) {
var rate = document.getElementById("intRate").value;
if (rate.length === 0) {
    errMessages += "Interest rate can't be left empty";
}
if (!(rate >= 3 && rate <= 16)) {
    errMessages += "Rate must be between 3 and 16 inclusive";
}
if (isNaN(rate)) {
    errMessages += "Rate must be  a number";
}
return errMessages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which can match strings based on a number of rules. In your case, something like this can validate that your value is only digits:

```
if (rate.match(/^\d*\.?\d+$/)) {
    // rate only has numbers
} else {
    // rate has other characters
}
```

**Edit:**

If you're not allowed to use regular expressions, `isNaN`, `typeof`, or other built-in functions for this purpose and *have* to explicitly loop through character-by-character (is this a school assignment, if so it would be nice if you post your own attempt to solve it first), then you can loop through the string contents and check if it's a digit or decimal. (You'll likely also want to ensure that only one decimal is present.)

Here's something to get you started:

```
var index, character;
for (index = 0; index < rate.length; index += 1) {

    character = rate[index];
    // Test to see if character is a digit or decimal here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseFloat like this

```
function valIntRate(errMessages) {

  var val = document.getElementById("intRate").value
  var rate = parseFloat(val);
  if (rate.toString() != val) 
  // any letters will be removed so if there is anything not number or dot this will be true
  {
    errMessages += "Must be a number";
  }
  if (rate.length === 0) {
    errMessages += "Interest rate can't be left empty";
  }


  if (rate < 3 || rate > 16) {
    errMessages += "Rate must be between 3 and 16 inclusive";
  }

  return errMessages;
}
```